# Loop over multiple columns in a merge in R

Tags: r, for-loop, merge

I am trying to loop the merging of two dataframes over multiple columns, but I'm having trouble with the code and haven't been able to find any answers on SO. Here are some example data frames:

```
box <- c(5,7,2)
year <- c(1999,1999,1999)
rep5 <- c(5,5,5)
rep7 <- c(7,7,7)
rep2 <- c(2,2,2)
df1 <- data.frame(box,year,rep5,rep7,rep2)

box1 <- c(5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2)
box2 <- c(5,7,2,5,5,7,2,4,5,7,2,9)
year2 <- c(1999,1999,1999,2000,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999)
distance <- c(0,100,200,0,100,0,300,200,200,300,0,300)
df2 <- data.frame(box1,box2,year2,distance)

df1
  box year rep5 rep7 rep2
1   5 1999    5    7    2
2   7 1999    5    7    2
3   2 1999    5    7    2

df2
   box1 box2 year2 distance
1     5    5  1999        0
2     5    7  1999      100
3     5    2  1999      200
4     5    5  2000        0
5     7    5  1999      100
6     7    7  1999        0
7     7    2  1999      300
8     7    4  1999      200
9     2    5  1999      200
10    2    7  1999      300
11    2    2  1999        0
12    2    9  1999      300
```

What I am trying to do is get the distance information from df2 into df1, with df1 year matched to df2 year, df1 box matched to df2 box1, and df1 rep[i] matched to df2 box2. I can do this for a single df1 rep[i] column as follows:

```
merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("box", "rep5", "year"), by.y=c("box1", "box2", "year2"), all.x = TRUE)
```

this gives the desired output:

```
  box rep5 year rep7 rep2 distance
1   2    5 1999    7    2      200
2   5    5 1999    7    2        0
3   7    5 1999    7    2      100
```

However, in order to save doing this for each rep[i] column individually (I have a lot of these columns in the real data set), I'd like to be able to loop over those columns. Here is the code I have tried to do that:

```
reps <- c(df1$rep7, df1$rep2)
df3 <- for (i in reps) {merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("box", i, "year"), by.y=c("box1", "box2", "year2"), all.x = TRUE)}
df3
```

When I run that code, I get the error "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column." I also tried defining

```
reps <- c("rep7", "rep2")
```

When I run the same code using that definition, I get the result that df3 is NULL.

The output that I want (with the distance column renamed for clarity) is:

```
  box year rep5 rep7 rep2 dist5 dist7 dist2
1   2 1999    5    7    2   200   300     0
2   5 1999    5    7    2     0   100   200
3   7 1999    5    7    2   100     0   300
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help you can give me would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

My R life became so much easier when I learned about the libraries `dplyr` and `tidyr`, and the [concept of tidy data sets](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf). What you're trying to do above can be expressed as a `pivot`, and is pretty easy to do with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

I'm assuming what you really want, is to turn df2:

```
   box1 box2 year2 distance
1     5    5  1999        0
2     5    7  1999      100
3     5    2  1999      200
4     5    5  2000        0
5     7    5  1999      100
6     7    7  1999        0
7     7    2  1999      300
8     7    4  1999      200
9     2    5  1999      200
10    2    7  1999      300
11    2    2  1999        0
12    2    9  1999      300
```

into your output, with all those strange repetitions removed:

```
  box year dist5 dist7 dist2
1   2 1999   200   300     0
2   5 1999     0   100   200
3   7 1999   100     0   300
```

So you should pivot `box2` into columns, with your distance as the value. using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
box1 <- c(5,5,5,5,7,7,7,7,2,2,2,2)
box2 <- c(5,7,2,5,5,7,2,4,5,7,2,9)
year2 <- c(1999,1999,1999,2000,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999,1999)
distance <- c(0,100,200,0,100,0,300,200,200,300,0,300)
df2 <- data.frame(box1,box2,year2,distance)

# reshape it as desired
spread(df2, box2, distance,fill=0)
#Source: local data frame [4 x 7]

#  box1 year2   2   4   5   7   9
#1    2  1999   0   0 200 300 300
#2    5  1999 200   0   0 100   0
#3    5  2000   0   0   0   0   0
#4    7  1999 300 200 100   0   0
```

My recommendation: learn to use `dplyr` and `tidyr`. It makes life so, so much easier.

Comment: There really isn't a need for `dplyr` there at all. `spread(data, box2, distance, fill = 0)`

Comment: No, there isn't, but they go together like Jack and Jill so i figured I'd include them so he knows what to Google.

Comment: I'm a huge `dplyr` fan, but I'm 100% with @RichardScriven here. This is a nice answer, but using a pipe makes it intimidating to users who haven't seen it before. Moreover, using a pipe is completely pointless with a single function. Piping is great to turn nested "inside-out" stuff into linear left-to-right stuff. When you don't have nesting, piping is just a weird habit. My advice is to keep your recommendation for the OP to look into `dplyr`, but don't make knowledge of dplyr a prerequisite for using your answer just so you can use a single `%>%`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm new to both R and Stack Overflow, so I appreciate the tips.

Comment: @emesrever sure thing! If you edit your answer and provide a dplyr-less version I'll even give you an upvote ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering, @emesrever! Unfortunately, I do not want to turn df2. I have the repetition columns in df1 because I'm creating a distance matrix for a Mantel test, so I need a matrix that has the distance between every pair of active boxes in a given year. The real df2 data frame is huge and has lots of information that I don't need, so I really just need to pull out the distance information in the way I described above. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @cas I guess I don't fully understand what you require, then, sorry! My gut suspicion is that you can still break down what you need to do into a combination of joins and pivots, and generate a distance matrix in that way. I don't have time right now to write a full answer, but I can tell you that looping and merging is not what you want to do.